# Removing <where> timestamp element from kml file Google My Tracks

Tags: element, kml, where-clause, google-earth, xmlstarlet

I have been playing around with Google "My Tracks" on Android and importing the tracks into Google Earth. When I do, I get the time bar at the top and the track will play as you drove it, like an animation of your track. I want to remove the time aspect of that track and the time aspect of the points that you made during that track.

I went into the KML file and saw that each point had a time stamp to it. I have been trying to remove the element responsible for the time aspect of the actual track first using:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/when" text.kml
```

As for the Placemarks I would assume the process would be similar if I could fix get the syntax right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kml structure is as follows, the  element is the one that I want to remove, not exactly sure if Google Earth will be happy with no element there or just having it be blank.

```
xmlstarlet el -u text.kml 

kml
kml/Document
kml/Document/Folder
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/Point
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/Point/coordinates
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/TimeStamp
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/TimeStamp/when
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/description
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/name
kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/styleUrl
kml/Document/Folder/name
kml/Document/Folder/open
kml/Document/Placemark
kml/Document/Placemark/ExtendedData
kml/Document/Placemark/ExtendedData/Data
kml/Document/Placemark/ExtendedData/Data/value
kml/Document/Placemark/Point
kml/Document/Placemark/Point/coordinates
kml/Document/Placemark/TimeStamp
kml/Document/Placemark/TimeStamp/when
kml/Document/Placemark/description
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/altitudeMode
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/ExtendedData
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/ExtendedData/SchemaData
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/gx:coord
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/when
kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:interpolate
kml/Document/Placemark/name
kml/Document/Placemark/styleUrl
kml/Document/Schema
kml/Document/Schema/gx:SimpleArrayField
kml/Document/Schema/gx:SimpleArrayField/displayName
kml/Document/Style
kml/Document/Style/IconStyle
kml/Document/Style/IconStyle/Icon
kml/Document/Style/IconStyle/Icon/href
kml/Document/Style/IconStyle/hotSpot
kml/Document/Style/IconStyle/scale
kml/Document/Style/LineStyle
kml/Document/Style/LineStyle/color
kml/Document/Style/LineStyle/width
kml/Document/atom:author
kml/Document/atom:author/atom:name
kml/Document/name
kml/Document/open
kml/Document/visibility
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default namespace problem (see [5.1: Namespaces and default namspace](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html)).

```
xmlstarlet ed -N k=http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 -d '/k:kml/k:Document/k:Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/k:when' text.kml
```

On versions before 1.2.0, `-N gx=http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2` will be required as well.

Comment: Thanks but I had no luck. Didn't delete any records... I will try to upload the file.